# How to carry paper Oregon hunting license and tag

Tags: united-states, hunting, legality

Oregon offers two types of hunting/fishing licenses and tags: a phone app, which is unreliable at best when you don't have an Internet connection, and paper documents you print yourself on regular 8.5/11 paper. I used the app for the last two years, but decided to go with paper this year. What's the best way to carry the paper documents? You have to write on the tag, so laminating it won't work, unless you can "un-laminate" it with scissors or a pocket knife. Also, if folding is required, laminating the license wouldn't be great either. Maybe vacuum-sealing the documents would work, then I could just cut the vacuum bag open if I needed to show my license or use a tag?

Answer (score 6):

To quote the [Oregon Hunting regulations](https://www.eregulations.com/oregon/hunting/general-hunting-regulations):

> The owner of a game mammal tag that kills a game mammal for which a paper tag is issued, shall immediately validate the tag by writing on the tag, in ink, the date and time of harvest, and the Wildlife Management Unit where harvest occurred; and attach the tag in plain sight securely to the game mammal.
>
> 1. To keep the tag legible, one option is to place it in a plastic bag to protect it.
> 2. Paper tags must be signed upon purchase or prior to use in the field.
> 3. It is unlawful to have in possession an unsigned tag and/or reproduction/photocopied/resized tag(s).
> 4. Resized: In relation to permits and tags, resized means to change the dimensions of a permit or tag, either electronically or physically, from the original size as printed on 8.5" x 11" (letter) paper; trimming to the border of the document itself after printing to original size is allowed

To me, this means you must sign it when you buy it, but then you need to be able to write on it once you have killed an animal.

I suspect that, as it is the #1 bullet point, that the vast majority are done with a paper bag and zip-tie or similar.

Personally I would carry it in a ziploc style plastic bag with a zip-tie and a pen. Then on use, you have everything you need to tag the animal.

I don't know how the validation on the app works; it may be that you don't need an internet connection for it to work. However, you still need to provide certain information with the carcass:

> Electronic Tags:
>
> > When the owner of any game mammal tag kills a game mammal for which an electronic tag is issued the owner shall immediately validate the tag by pressing the “Validate” button on the image of the tag in the MyODFW mobile application. Follow the prompts and complete the tag validation process by clicking “Save”. After validation a confirmation number will become visible.
>
> 1. In addition to validating a tag electronically, the tag owner’s name, date of birth, ODFW ID number, harvest date, and confirmation number must be written in ink on material of the tag owner’s choice (options
>    include flagging tape, duct tape, and paper in a plastic bag to protect it), and attached in plain sight securely to the game mammal.

In this case I would use flagging tape, as it is light, easily transported and readily written on permanently.

Comment: Thank you! With the app, offline tagging is supposed to work, but it doesn't always.